# Typescript: type one key based on input of another

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

let's say I have the following interface:

```
interface A extends Entity {
  propA: string;
  propB: number;
  propC: boolean;
}
```

I'm can query the objects behind this interface by building filters in the following way:

```
const filters: Filter<A>[] = [
  { op: 'eq', field: 'propA', value: 'test' },
  { op: 'in', field: 'propB', value: [1,2,3] },
  { op: 'exists', field: 'propC' }
]
```

All values for `op` are valid for all of the fields and field types. But two of the examples above have an additional `value` property. This property is mandatory for certain values of `op`, and depending on the value, should be a single scalar, or an array of scalars.

I got it covered so far, but this is where I get stuck: The type of `value` must match the type of the property on the object we're filtering on.

So this should be valid:

```
// single value operators
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propA', value: 'test' };
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'noteq', field: 'propB', value: 5 };
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propC', value: true };

// multi value operators
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: ['test1', 'test2'] };
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propB', value: [5, 6, 7] };
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'notIn', field: 'propC', value: [true] };

// no value operators
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'exists', field: 'propC' };
```

but this not:

```
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propA', value: 5 }; // A.propA is string, not number
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'noteq', field: 'propB', value: true }; // A.propB is number, not boolean
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: 'test' }; // in operator expects array (of strings, in this case)
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: [5, 6, 7] }; // A.propA is string, operator is in, so value should be an array of strings, not of numbers
const filter: Filter<A> = { op: 'exists', field: 'propC', value: true }; // exists operator does not expect a value
```

How do I do that?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
export interface Entity {
  id: number;
  isActive: boolean;
}

interface ComparisonFilter {
  op: 'eq'|'noteq'|'gt'|'gte'|'lt'|'lte'|'beginsWith'|'endsWith'|'contains';
  value: ???;
}

interface NoncomparisonFilter {
  op: 'exist'|'notExist';
}

interface ListFilter {
  op: 'in'|'notIn';
  value: ???[];
}

type FieldFilter<T extends Entity> = (
  ComparisonFilter |
  NoncomparisonFilter |
  ListFilter
) & { field: keyof T };

interface GroupingFilter<T extends Entity> {
  op: 'AND'|'OR';
  items: Filter<T>[];
}

export type Filter<T extends Entity> = FieldFilter<T> | GroupingFilter<T>;
```

Comment: There is an inconsistency.  You expect Filter to get T extends Entity, when A interface does not meet requirements for Entity. COuld you please provide more information about that

Comment: `interface ComparisonFilter {
  op: 'eq'|'noteq'|'gt'|'gte'|'lt'|'lte'|'beginsWith'|'endsWith'|'contains';
  value: string; 
}`

Comment: is `???` valid type, i guess not.

Comment: @captain-yossarian you are very right! Cut out a little too much when I tried to minimize the code that I paste here. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create union of allowed types

```js
interface A {
    propA: string;
    propB: number;
    propC: boolean;
}

export interface Entity {
    id: number;
    isActive: boolean;
}
type WithoutValue = 'exist'


interface ComparisonFilter {
    op: 'ne' | 'eq' | 'noteq' | 'gt' | 'gte' | 'lt' | 'lte' | 'beginsWith' | 'endsWith' | 'contains';

}

interface NoncomparisonFilter {
    op: WithoutValue | 'notExist';
}

interface ListFilter {
    op: 'in' | 'notIn';
}

type ApplyAll<T, Filters extends { op: string }> = {
    op: Exclude<Filters['op'], WithoutValue>;
} & Enchance<T> | { op: WithoutValue, field: keyof T }

type AllFilters =
    | ComparisonFilter
    | NoncomparisonFilter
    | ListFilter;

type FieldFilter<T> = ApplyAll<T, AllFilters>

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Enchance<T> = Values<{
    [P in keyof T]: { field: P, value: T[P] | Array<T[P]> }
}>

interface GroupingFilter<T> {
    op: 'AND' | 'OR';
    items: Filter<T>[];
}

export type Filter<T> = FieldFilter<T> | GroupingFilter<T>;



/**
 * Valid
 */
// single value operators
const filter1: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propA', value: 'test' };
const filter2: Filter<A> = { op: 'ne', field: 'propB', value: 5 };
const filter3: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propC', value: true };

// multi value operators
const filter4: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: ['test1', 'test2'] };
const filter5: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propB', value: [5, 6, 7] };
const filter6: Filter<A> = { op: 'notIn', field: 'propC', value: [true] };

// no value operators
const filter7: Filter<A> = { op: 'exist', field: 'propC' };


// Invalid

const filter_: Filter<A> = { op: 'eq', field: 'propA', value: 5 }; // A.propA is string, not number
const filter__: Filter<A> = { op: 'ne', field: 'propB', value: true }; // A.propB is number, not boolean
const filter___: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: 'test' }; // in operator expects array (of strings, in this case)
const filter____: Filter<A> = { op: 'in', field: 'propA', value: [5, 6, 7] }; // A.propA is string, operator is in, so value should be an array of strings, not of numbers
const filter_____: Filter<A> = { op: 'exist', field: 'propC', value: true }; // exists operator does not expect a value
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20QBygHt9UAuZAZzClAHMBuHPQkgIQpAFcBbAI2hM8BYvgDCFPkSIAbCHBBMAvliwQAHviJQwyUJFiIUAUXDAwAT0zNcwACadeAqELzBKqBGGAA3CJOk5BWUsS3wUAHVzAAsiLjAANTgZLhQAXmQAcg13MEzVLH1oeCRkMSIefDhaSiIQADFgGQNrYRIKTJAITOQAHyyIAEce-s6iSGG%20rLo8qcyZ7rnmkazmxdGBOlBKKLBoleyQOx2Yg4Q6sDhtzKYsFULwYqNkADk688rq9zrGtahWvDtZC7WLxJIpFCjEDjYzqXI3O6qIqGUoAGVyvxa2Da%20A6oAO0LAAEkQAj7mEUKh8PgZBZUDIZAAeAAqABpkJjoJRkBpIEduRhkEDqLQQHRkEoAHzIDLYwG45CwhApOwQRmcqCUADamRImQAuuyQXFEslUpLlMgAGSKkAIaIKJAs6X9QVA41gs0QdkwYAQGQOZAAawgFiIMGQzIlqgpaAZGu5aRsU3KnxqPyaBmT-TedoqVXTDUz0GzyHR1A1t1jjX9dg1zplaGptPpTLZcZkCclMYs4WQ4NSlAbGWZWpDYYjzP1Pb7pntjrVzOlGQHECHctwWoACnoQMHQ%20HI-qKILfbWKFv2T4vRRR1v9VNUFAoHALCzt-rpSopUjHiiUAA4sQXD4PQ9ZLgCuBApkqAvAAIgcADyABKCLCOYEA8JQFDgZKWr6iEaiaNoujVsWUDDhyfoBrhUxAXEoFirhtyqAA9AAVOxODsf2yT2NxrFYKxrFUPQcjINeEJCuEL5gNolBYOcIDUMgvp-AAjDh5GMqgy6YNJHRDJkPrUYGmSsKQxkSTeWSQNQPRKEwSkqWpBgAExaX8Ol6W6CqdN0JnnlkFlsFZkmpBQACsEpOXULnkQAzJ5BjeY2vmGcMgUBh0FliGFNk0KkMVsSJPBcM0wDWVJJDQHAcmaopcW6K50AACzJdAqWygZWT4llZkWag%20UQhQOp2WA6lWZk41uQaxXOc15GRR1FG6WlPWZH1qmmTloihVeNlapF7IAGzsgA7A%20jmNcpi1-CdK1dfp0GEiSVlntlwWiHlB0jcgWqFRAV23MJyDQlVRU1bJ8k3fFfznY9a3ddBOT2f1u0kHlxUlcgJKSfxsN3QYAD6iM%20RtRno19JBDb9EXINFjnIKDqAAHSDXo3IivQ7KEmDTglgt21-MTpNUV5SPPX5XTvTt1P4PtEP%20MggMxczIlsyFnP8-w0C8%20MyBSLI8ggITwsk6LZPrdBW0fQNoi00rHTjQ5DDq7u0m1fVPKaBAXjctUL5WAAFIe3NipQ7KgCr0TuMgCBwJQEAAJRmy1UCi5b4spZL6W9aSVPmQ7w300dp0XcD7uaw72vh3Q7JQ3V2ja6A7K1ErVCggGhsoAoyCB6%20QoRnXkdgwbh7cLrDVC%20nmdZ-WucU3CaPbUFReYyXyuq0zoOo2A3KN97dhEGuY%206Bo4ReP3StAA)

More explanation about this pattern you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202)

Comment: I would disclose your affiliation to the linked content

Comment: Does this handle arrays of values as well?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer good point! I made an update. Yes, now it allows array of values.

Comment: Thanks for the example @captain-yossarian. It doesn't quite cover the case though. The operator dictates whether value is a single field ('eq', 'ne', 'lt'), an array ('in', 'notIn') or completely absent ('exists', 'notExists'). Also, in your example, if the end user makes a mistake, not only the value is marked as invalid, but also the property, because the compiler can't match them anymore

Comment: please provide more examples what are you expecting

Comment: I've added some more examples to the original post. Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: You have provided `op: 'ne'` but I can't find it in your type declarations